# FAB transition animation that works below android L?

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, android-transitions

I read a lot topics on Material design and sawed lot of example on it. Recently I installed a calendar application that called [Today Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.underwood.calendar_beta&hl=en) which have a Material design and Requires `Android 4.1 and up`, also the animations and transitions are all working on 4.1 and later.

The FAB's transition is very nice along with other views. I want to implement it in my application that requires API Level 14+, when the user clicks on the FAB it will transition to buttom with nice animation.

My design looks like this:

[image]

How to implement this transition?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Which animation are you talking about?

Comment: @XaverKapeller: FAB moves to button with nice animation.

Comment: I have no idea what animation you are talking about.